# Is a polynomial always reducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm studying abstract algebra. The following seems to be too difficult for me:

Let $p(x)$ be a second degree polynomial with integer coefficients. Is the polynomial $p(p(x)+x)$ always reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?

Comment: Have you tried, for instance, inserting $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, and just see what you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** As $p(\alpha)=0 \implies p(p(\alpha)+\alpha)=0$, we always have $p(x)$ as a factor.

Comment: More generally $p(q(x))-p(r(x))$ is always divisible by $q(x)-r(x)$. (Roots is a good heuristic, but since $p$ might have repeated roots, it is possible that $p(p(x)+x)$ has fewer instances of the root.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The general rule is interesting. I assumed the case of $p$ a quadratic with repeated root is trivially reducible and hence so is $p(p(x)+x)$.